# org-insert-todo-subheading-respect-content

Tags: org-mode

There is no `org-insert-todo-subheading-respect-content`, but there is a `org-insert-todo-heading-respect-content`.

Why?

Also, if `describe-function` could show the source of that function, then maybe I could be able to implement it myself.

So, two questions then ;)

Comment: On Fedora, `describe-function` includes a link to the source of a function (that's also the case when you build/install from upstream sources of course). On other distros, you might have to install an additional package to provide the sources: what system are you running on and how do you install Emacs?

Comment: I'm on NixOS and I've put emacs in the configuration.nix

Answer (score 0):

After org-insert-heading-respect-content(), tap C-Tab to indent the heading one level. Repeated taps on C-Tab will indent the heading at all possible levels, leaving the choice up to you.

For me, I find this easy enough. It makes a separate command for indenting one level (if that's what you mean by "subheading") superfluous.

Comment: First of all, C-Tab doesn't work in terminal, but most importantly, I want to achieve this with one command, just like org-insert-todo-subheading, but respecting the content;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(defun org-insert-subheading-respect-content (&optional)
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-insert-heading-respect-content t))
    (org-insert-todo-subheading t)))
```

I looked at the definition of the regular heading respect content and just adapted the above from that function.

I don't use NixOS so I am not sure why you can't see the definition. But `describe-function` does link to the file where the function is defined, namely `org.el`